# Na Espelho / Nas Espelho

Tags: significado

In the mirror.  Would it not properly translate to Nas Espelho..

Because you have Na (in) and well you want to say As (the) mirror.

= Nas Espelho   the proper way to say

Meu reflexo aparece nas espelho

Comment: You might want to review the use of em followed by an article.

Answer (score 5):

No, it would not, it would be "no espelho". Word-for-word:

> in + the + mirror

translates to

> em + [o/a/os/as] + espelho

"Em" is the translation for "in"; "na" is a combination of "em" + "a" ("in the").

The definite article in Portuguese agrees with both the grammatical gender (masculine/feminine) and number (singular/plural) of what it refers to, a little like "he", "she", and "they" do in English. So "as" means "the" only for a feminine plural word. "Espelho" is a masculine and singular word, so its "the" should be "o", not "as":

> em + o + espelho

And "em" + "o" becomes "no", not "na":

> no espelho